# How to use for loop in a html Document

Tags: python, html, for-loop

[image: single for loop]

I want to make a Website with a map for an organizer of a fair.
So i got the point where i need to implement an interleaved for loop.

```
   <div class="table">
   <div class="tr">
   @var entry_a;@
   @var entry_b;@
   @var loop_i;@
   @var loop_y;@
             @for loop_i = 0; loop_i < context.length; loop_i++@
               @entry_a = context[loop_i];@
               @for loop_y = 0; loop_y < entry_a.length; loop_y++@
                  @entry_b = entry_a[loop_y];@
                  <div id="#entry_b['id']#">
                     @if (entry_b['belegt'] == 0)@
                           <div class="td">#entry_b['col1']#</div>
                     @else@
                           <div class="td_b">#entry_b['col1']#</div>
                     @endif@
                  </div>
                @endfor@
             @endfor@
    </div>
</div>
```

my json data looks like this:

```
  self.data_a =[
  {
        "0": {
           "id": "0",
           "col1": "A 1",
           "belegt": "0"
        },
        "1": {
           "id": "1",
           "col1": "B 1",
           "belegt": "1"
        },
        "2": {
           "id": "2",
           "col1": "C 1",
           "belegt": "0"
        },
        "3": {
           "id": "3",
           "col1": "D 1",
           "belegt": "1"
        }
    },
    {
        "0": {
           "id": "0",
           "col1": "A 2",
           "belegt": "0"
        },
        "1": {
           "id": "1",
           "col1": "B 2",
           "belegt": "1"
        },
        "2": {
           "id": "2",
           "col1": "C 2",
           "belegt": "0"
        },
        "3": {
           "id": "3",
           "col1": "D 2",
           "belegt": "1"
        }
    }
  ]
```

but somehow when i use the debugger it doesnt trigger the for loops.
I'm happer for every help.

Comment: What is this language in your HTML document, with `@`?

Comment: should be python.

Comment: That's neither Python, nor pure HTML. What template engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
code:
for x in range(len(data_a)):
    for n in data_a[x]:
        print(n)
output:
{'id': '0', 'col1': 'A 1', 'belegt': '0'}
{'id': '1', 'col1': 'B 1', 'belegt': '1'}
{'id': '2', 'col1': 'C 1', 'belegt': '1'}
{'id': '3', 'col1': 'D 1', 'belegt': '1'}
{'id': '0', 'col1': 'A 2', 'belegt': '0'}
{'id': '1', 'col1': 'B 2', 'belegt': '0'}
{'id': '2', 'col1': 'C 2', 'belegt': '0'}
{'id': '3', 'col1': 'D 2', 'belegt': '0'}
```

I guess this what you are expecting. if not, please write the expected output

Answer (score 0):

i changed th json format to:

```
  self.data_a =[
    [
        {
           "id": "0",
           "col1": "A 1",
           "belegt": "0"
        },
        {
           "id": "1",
           "col1": "B 1",
           "belegt": "1"
        },
        {
           "id": "2",
           "col1": "C 1",
           "belegt": "1"
        },
        {
           "id": "3",
           "col1": "D 1",
           "belegt": "1"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
           "id": "0",
           "col1": "A 2",
           "belegt": "0"
        },
        {
           "id": "1",
           "col1": "B 2",
           "belegt": "0"
        },
        {
           "id": "2",
           "col1": "C 2",
           "belegt": "0"
        },
        {
           "id": "3",
           "col1": "D 2",
           "belegt": "0"
        }
    ]
  ]
```